# Plimus Buyanywhere API

Tags: e-commerce, payment-gateway, bluesnap

I am trying to develop forms for Upgrade Subscription and Cancel Subscription with Plimus API from my Yii framework.

It seems like there is a lack of documentation/tutorial on this 'BuyAnywhere' API. Is there a good site that explains this process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my experience they don't have a API in common meaning of this word, I assume this is a "loud" title of store owners being able to customize view and custom fields for the form + receive payment notifications to URL of their choice.